# Question just ... vanished?

Tags: discussion

There was recently a very angry question from a fellow who felt like he was failing to get traction on -- I believe -- superuser.com, and ended up getting involved in silly flame wars.  I wanted to reference it in order to ask a meta question about IPSE and online culture, but it seems to be gone.

Is there any way to find out what happened to it?  I do not have any reference to it, and the next download to data.stackexchange.com is not for some time.

Could be I imagined the whole thing and the question was really on some other SE that I stumbled upon, or I'm just ... completely loco.  Hard to tell at this point...

Comment: You could ask a mod (or 10k user) in SuperUser (or other site) to screenshot the question and get it back to you

Comment: The question was reposted at https://meta.superuser.com/q/12710.

Comment: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/5823/why-is-the-superuser-community-so-hostile-and-arrogant-towards-new-users

Comment: More often than not when questions "just vanish" it's a good thing. It means the system is working as intended. Not always, mind you, but more often than not.

Comment: @apaul that's fair enough in the general sense.  I'm not sure I really need the question to come back on the board, though I do believe there is an IP-type question lurking in there *somewhere*.  Mostly I wanted it for research, so I can delve for such a question to post myself, without having to actually do battle with a bunch of angry sysadmins...  ;D  My biggest complaint is that a deleted question appears to be *deleted* instead of marked with some kind of deleted flag and still visible via the query page at data.stackexchange.com.

Comment: We've had some mixed discussion/opinions about whether these kinds of questions should be on topic here. https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/search?q=Stack+Exchange

Comment: @apaul yep I have seen a few of those.  It's tough to walk the line between a meta-appropriate post "I need adjudication of my dispute here" vs a "Help me be non-inflammatory in an online forum" which one *might just* be able to sneak into IPS.SE main site.  Hmm.  To the other point, I'm not sure if I have permission to see deleted posts; I know on the query page if I ask for "where DeletionDate is not null" gives me nada.

Comment: I had to check the privileges page. You should be able to view deleted posts on the main site, not too sure about data explorer though.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157462/can-some-metadata-about-deleted-posts-be-included-in-data-se

Comment: @apaul hey that's great!  That q speaks right to what I was wondering about.  Thanks a bundle for pointing me to that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question on IPS was deleted by the community.

The author made [a similar post on Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/q/12710/96202).

Comment: Thanks!  This gives me enough for what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, I was informed of it - and suggested he take it to our meta, and it was closed here by a few users.

Sadly, I don't feel that it went very constructively on our site - it was the right place, but its one of those situations where I didn't feel we were able to get through to the user.

I've addressed the specific comments he had but he kept pushing the boundaries of "be nice" with the rest of it and comments.

We're *always* happy to address direct, specific *civil* critiques of how we do things on Super User

Comment: Thanks for the update, I appreciate it because I wanted to compare the fellow's complaint with my memories of **extremely similar** complaints I've seen on other sites (wikipedia is one) and also going back as far as some 20 years ago on usenet newsgroups.  I'm not yet sure how to bring it all together, but there's *something* going on with the dynamics of online communities which makes this sort of thing unfortunately all too common.  I do hope the fellow gets his serenity back...

Comment: I hope so too! Its also possible though, that people complain about the same things could also mean, well, people have the same issues with... communities that are different from what they're used to. SU's kinda meant to have a wider audience so we try to be mindful of that

Comment: Is it also a coincidence that almost all such questions are written by new members? I have seen just *one* such complaint by a senior member on SE sites.

Comment: Maybe they're expecting things to work like a forum. Maybe the ones who don't like it leave - and never come back, sometimes after posting angry rants... leaving us with some degree of confirmational bias...

Comment: Senior members have chat privileges and complain there...